# If statement not called with NSStrings equaling each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, comparison

Can someone please explain why this code doesn't work? Both Theorem and title are NSStrings, and when displayed in the console, it is clear that they match at some point, but the nslog@"HI" is never printed. Thanks!

```
if (Theorem==title) {
        NSLog(@"hi");

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setValue:title forKey:@"title"];
        [defaults setValue:info forKey:@"info"];
        [defaults setValue:subInfo forKey:@"subInfo"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%@",Theorem);
        NSLog(@"%@",title);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `isEqualToString:` method to compare the value of two strings. Using the `==` operator just compares the two pointers.

```
if ([Theorem isEqualToString:title]) {
} else {
}
```

Comment: This is the answer! Thank you so much! I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.